# Linebreaks in comments on Stack Exchange questions and answers

Tags: discussion, comments, markdown

My original question was going to be how to add line breaks when commenting on a question or answer.  I looked at the [markdown editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) page, and found that it's not supported, at least as far as I can tell.

So my question is, why not?  I know comments are supposed to be short, but splitting two thoughts into separate paragraphs would make [my comment on someone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912987/creating-css-map-files-when-minifying-css-files/28770541?noredirect=1#comment45844692_28770541) much more readable.

Should I just have commented twice?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wasn't adding code.  Both thoughts were merely comments on the suggested answer.

Comment: _"why not? "_ Comments are 3rd class citizens in the SO posting model. Having this feature would encourage noise, rather than well formed answers. If you have an answer that doesn't fit in a comment post it as answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Did you click the "my comment on someone's answer" link in the original question?  It very much *isn't* an answer, but it does contain two distinct thoughts.  Without a linebreak, it looks like a wall of text.

Comment: Anyway I doubt, someone would support such feature. You have other possibilities to separate and emphasize, use them.

Comment: @dfoverdx: so what's wrong with creating **two** comments then?

Comment: I redirected this dupe; the original it was pointed to was too focused on *code* line breaks to be a true dupe, IMO.

Comment: I'm curious why so this has so many down-votes? This is a legit question asked in the right place. It really shouldn't be DV'd just for being a dupe, the Close vote handles that, plus in this case, I'd argue it was tricky enough to find the right target that 5 voters missed it.  And "meta-I-disagree-with-your-suggstion" downvotes really oughtn't be used for, "I want to know why this is; it's confusing or feels illogical for these reasons".  That's what you WANT people to ask..

Answer (score 2):

> *"why not?"*

Comments are 3rd class citizens in the SO posting model. Having this feature would encourage noise, rather than well formed answers.

If you have an answer that doesn't fit in a comment post it as answer.

If you have another comment (paragraph) that wouldn't fit (look) well in a single comment, post another one.

Comment: "If you have an answer that doesn't fit in a comment post it as answer" - is that the case, though? The difference between what should be answer and a what should be a comment is content. You can have a **comment** that **does** fit into a comment and that you should **not** post as an answer, and yet this wouldn't address at all the linebreak matter (i.e. that a linebreak option would make a rightful comment way more readable and thus useful, while still falling within the characters limit that has been determined for rightful comments)

Answer (score 1):

Your comment doesn't seem to be requesting information or suggesting improvements, rather it seems to be adding additional information to the question. Therefore your comment belongs as an edit to the question.

Comment: Because it is his question.  What would you recommend for a third-party wanting to supply the same background information?